# Getting weird error message from Highstock / Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm currently working with Highstock / Highcharts and I wan't to load data through a json file, that I have. When I'm trying to get the data it gives me this error message in the console that I haven't seen before:

```
highstock.js:456 Uncaught TypeError: f.data.slice is not a function
```

And I'm trying to get the json data through this function. I'm only getting this error message when im entering the url for my `data.json`:

```
$.each(names, function (i, name) {

        var dataUrl = 'http://local.priceservice.dev/js/data.json';

        $.getJSON(dataUrl,    function (data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
            console.log(data)
        });
    });
```

I have never seen that message before and I've tried to search around, but I can't find someone that had the same issue as me.

Json:

```
{
    "priceSeries": {
        "2016-10-19T12:51:51.000Z": [[1451606400000, 18.0], [1454284800000, 19.0], [1456790400000, 17.0], [1456790400000, 15.0], [1459468800000, 15.0], [1462060800000, 15.0], [1464739200000, 15.0], [1467331200000, 15.0], [1470009600000, 15.0], [1472688000000, 15.0], [1475280000000, 15.0], [1477958400000, 15.0], [1480550400000, 15.0], [1483228800000, 15.0], [1485907200000, 15.0], [1488326400000, 15.0]],
        "2016-11-19T12:51:51.000Z": [[1451606400000, 19.0], [1454284800000, 20.0], [1456790400000, 18.0], [1456790400000, 16.0], [1459468800000, 16.0], [1462060800000, 16.0], [1464739200000, 16.0], [1467331200000, 16.0], [1470009600000, 16.0], [1472688000000, 16.0], [1475280000000, 16.0], [1477958400000, 16.0], [1480550400000, 16.0], [1483228800000, 16.0], [1485907200000, 16.0], [1488326400000, 16.0]]
    }
}
```

Highstock / Highcharts code:

```
$(function () {
    var seriesOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];
    /**
     * Create the chart when all data is loaded
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function createChart() {

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'hour',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1h'
            }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'
            }, {
                    type: 'week',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1w'
            }, {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
            }, {
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1y'
            }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
            }],
                inputEnabled: false, // it supports only days
                selected: 4 // all
            },
            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },

                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                }]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent',
                    showInNavigator: true
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2,
                split: true
            },

            series: seriesOptions
        });
    }

    $.each(names, function (i, name) {

        var dataUrl = 'http://local.priceservice.dev/js/data.json';

        $.getJSON(dataUrl,    function (data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
            console.log(data)
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data in series has to be an array. The series requires at least one object with data in the format like this:

```
series: [{
   data: [...] // <- has to be an array
}]
```

Your series looks like this:

```
series: [{
   name: ...,
   data: { // <- you put an object instead of an array with points
      "priceSeries": ...
   }
}]
```

The code above causes that slice is call on object, like this

```
var someObj = {};
someObj.slice(); // Uncaught TypeError: someObj.slice is not a function(…)
```

You should go in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/r3xfxymm/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped!

Comment: Great! Saved my hours of time. Thank you :)